# Updating PFObject not working as expcected

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, heroku, parse-server

Here I am trying to set a status field on each document within a collection (in mongoDB on a Parse-Server/Heroku).
The code below is not very complex, but for some reason it fails. I hope a new eye can point out what is wrong.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Book_List")
query.limit = 1024
query.findObjectsInBackground {
    (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil && objects != nil) {
        for book in objects! {
            book.setObject("0", forKey: "status")
            book.saveInBackground {
                (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
                if !success {print("FAILED.")} else {print("OK-OK.")}
                if error != nil {print("Error = \(String(describing: error))")}
            }
        }
    }

    if error != nil {
        print("Error = \(error.debugDescription)")
    }

    if objects == nil {
        print("We haven't found anything on Parse!!")
    }
}
```

I expect this to run and set a field ({"status": "0"}) on each loop. But I only see this in the debugging console:

```
FAILED.
Error = Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "Object not found." UserInfo={code=101, temporary=0, error=Object not found., NSLocalizedDescription=Object not found.})
... [Error]: Object not found. (Code: 101, Version: 1.17.1)
```

Since I get the objects with PFQuery-findObjectsInBackground they exist somewhere.
So why do I get this error message?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving each book individually, try saving it in one bulk using [+saveAllInBackground:block:](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(cm)saveAllInBackground:block:)

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Book_List")
query.limit = 1024
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) in
    if error == nil,
       let objects = objects {
        for book in objects {
            book.setObject("0", forKey: "status")
        }
        PFObject.saveAllInBackground(objects: objects) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if !success { print("FAILED.") } else { print("OK-OK.") }
            if error != nil { print("Error = \(String(describing: error))") }
        }
    }

    if error != nil {
        print("Error = \(error.debugDescription)")
    }

    if objects == nil {
        print("We haven't found anything on Parse!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but still get the same kind of error message:

[Error]: Object not found. (Code: 101, Version: 1.17.1) x (number of document  in the collection) times.
FAILED.

Comment: I find this "Object not found." somewhat puzzling.

Comment: I've never used it so can't help you further, sorry :(

Comment: No problem. I think I found the solution. Appearently it will let me modify an object only if I am logged in (while inserting a new one worked without being logged in).